# Getting value from database column Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

May be is simple but I have one table where I want to take value from one column. They are two records and always will be two records and I need value from second id.. Here is visual

```
id     key      value
 1    key_1     Value_1
 2    key_2     value_2
```

I want to take `value_2`. Here is what I have in my controller

```
$free = DB::table('settings')->select('value')->where('key', '=', 'free')->get();
    return View::make('site.cart.order', [
        'cart' => $cart,
        'free' => $free
    ]);
```

And in my view I'm trying this

```
@if( $total < $free['value'] )

   // loop
@endif
```

Currently I'm getting - `Undefined index: value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right Laravel returns a standard class there and you should access it like this.

```
$free->value
```

Instead of

```
$free['value']
```

But you have to change now it selects the first record

```
$free = DB::table('settings')->select('value')->where('key', '=', 'free')->first();
```

Then you can access it like

```
$free->value
```

Or if you don't want to change get() to first() you can access it like this because get() returns an array.

```
$free[0]->value
```

Comment: Got this: `'Trying to get property of non-object'`

Comment: Could you give me the output of $free when you var_dump it?

Comment: This, which is correct info `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#285 (1) { ["value"]=> string(3) "101" } }`

Comment: is it big difference between `get()` and `first()`? I mean which one is preferable for use?

Comment: No there is no big difference get() returns an array with all the records and first() fetches only on record.

Comment: In my case record which I put in `select` option. So in my case may be is better to use `first()`

Comment: Yes because you only need one value so there is no need for get() because you don't need multiple records

Answer (score 1):

Use `first()` instead of `get()` and use `$free->value`, `get()` return an array of object

Comment: Got this: `'Trying to get property of non-object'`